# Get product permalink and ID using Next JS and Commerce.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, e-commerce, next-router

I'm wondering if anybody can point me in the right direction. I'm following the dynamic routes documentation on Next JS site - https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Currently I'm rendering all products on the `products` page. I'm using `getServersideProps` to make the API call. Here is the products page:

```
import Link from "next/link";

const Products = ({ data }) => {
  const products = data;
  return (
    <>
      {products.map(({ id, name, seo: { description } }) => (
        <div className="product" key={id}>
          <h2>{name}</h2>
          <p>{description}</p>
          <Link href={`/products/${permalink}`}>
            <a>View</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const headers = {
    "X-Authorization": process.env.CHEC_API_KEY,
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  const res = await fetch("https://api.chec.io/v1/products", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
  });
  const data = await res.json();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: data, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

export default Products;
```

In the Link I am using the permalink to direct people to a single product

```
<Link href={`/products/${permalink}`}>
            <a>View</a>
          </Link>
```

This is set up as `products/[name].js` in the structure, with `index.js` being the all products page.

Now on my single product page, `[name].js` I would like to run another `getServersideProps` to call the API and get the product - but I want to use the `product id` however I'd only like to display the `permalink/slug` in the URL.

Here is the `[name].js` page:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Product = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router);

  return <p></p>;
};

export default Product;
```

Of course this is just logging out the Object with what I can access. The query shows [name]: "product-name", which is great - I could now make a call for all products and filter the product the that matches this slug but I want to use the product `id` instead. Commerce.js has an request where I can `request` a single product just by using its `id`. How would I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have a problem with SSR, if you want to pass the id and only show the slug in the URL how will SSR know of your ID if no one will be there to pass it?

You can try something like this, but it will work only in SPA mode.

```
<Link href={{ pathname: '/products' query: { prodId: id} }} as={permalink} />
```

I think you can't hide the ID form URL if you want SSR to work.

**Edit:**

If you want a workaround for improved SEO you could have a structure like `products/[...slug].js` and then using the catch-all your path will be like `/products/342/product-name` is a compromise but it will work with SSR.